# Exel - Convert date from "month day, year" to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: excel, vba

Is there an easy way to convert a date such as:

Dec 21, 2019

to:

21/12/2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
CDate("Dec 21, 2019")
```

Here is a [link](https://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/vba-convert-string-to-date-with-cdate/) to a nice tutorial :)

Comment: Do note that this will not work if the system date setting is anything other than DD/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score 1):

The output of `CDate` is dependent on the regional or system-defined settings of the user's computer. To force the format regardless of these settings, it is preferrable to use the [`Format` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications):

```
Format("Dec 21, 2019", "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below formula and then change the date format

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT("Dec 21, 2019","dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

Hope it helps!